# How to set default integer value in typeorm entity with mongodb

Tags: typescript, typeorm

Hi I am using typeorm with mongodb, I tried to assign a default value for a field under User entity like below,

```
@Column('int',  {default: 0})
tokenVersion: number;
```

and ended up with `undefined`, when I tried to access it from resolver.

I tried `@BeforeInsert` still no luck.

if i do it in the way below,

```
@Column('int',  {default: 0})
tokenVersion: number = 0;
```

it is simply retuning 0 all the time.

any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I last used TypeORM and I have never used it in combination with MongoDB. However, I think it might be caused by one of these two reasons:

1. The [documentation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/entities.md#column-options) of TypeORM states that the `default` parameter should be a string. I suspect that the `0` might be treated as a falsy parameter and thus will be ignored. You could try using `default: '0'` instead.
2. There used to be a [bug report](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3799) that looks a lot like your issue. I'm not sure if they fixed it as I cannot see the reason why the issue got closed. Perhaps this issue got solved in a newer version, so I would suggest you check if there are any updates available.

Having said that, I still find it odd that both the `@BeforeInsert` and property default `tokenVersion: number = 0` don't solve you problem. If the above solutions don't work, I would give the [@BeforeInsert](https://typeorm.io/#/listeners-and-subscribers/beforeinsert) hook another try. If it still doesn't work, perhaps you could share that part of the code as well.

Comment: I can not make it '0' as a String, actually its a JWT token version. if I make it a sting i will not be able to add 1. Am I right?